# Allocating boot time memory using dts configuration

Tags: memory, kernel, driver, dts

I am working with a particular encoder which uses 512M boot time allocated memory. I am supposed to allocate the memory through dts file configuration. The physical memory is devided into low and high as below in the dts file:

```
    /* 256MB at 0x0 */
    memory@0 {
            device_type = "memory";
            reg =  <0x0 0x00000000 0x0 0x10000000>;
    };

    /* 2GB at 0x8010000000 */
    memory@8000000000 {
            device_type = "memory";
            reg =  <0x80 0x10000000 0x0 0x80000000>;
    };
```

Now I want to allocate the boot time carved out memory from the high memory. I can think of creating a dts entry as below

```
encoder: encoder@0xxxxxxxxx {
    compatible = "xyz, abc";
    reg=    <0x0 0x80000000 0x0 0x20000000>;
}
```

Here the encoder@xxxx is the actual device entry and it has already a set of register region as below:

```
    encoder: encoder@0xxxxxxxxx{
        compatible = "xyz, abc";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        reg = <0x0 0xxxxxxxxxx 0x0 0x1234>;
        status = "disabled";
    };
```

So after adding the carvedout memory the entry would look like this:

```
    encoder: encoder@0xxxxxxxxx{
        compatible = "xyz, abc";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        reg = <0x0 0xxxxxxxxxx 0x0 0x1234>;
        reg=  <0x0 0x80000000 0x0 0x20000000>;
        status = "disabled";
    };
```

Would this work? I am not sure though how the driver code would know where is the start address of the carved out memory and the size of it? 
Can anyone please help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by creating curving out memory from the lower part of the high memory for my device. To do this I modified my dtsi file to reflect the mew memory map as below:

```
/* 256MB at 0x0 - this is the low memory region*/
        memory@0 {
                device_type = "memory";
                reg =  <0x0 0x00000000 0x0 0x10000000>;
        };

        /* 1GB at 0x8010000000 - high memory region, this used to be 2GB earlier. I curved out to 1GB and allocated 1GB to my device*/
        memory@8000000000 {
                device_type = "memory";
                reg =  <0x80 0x10000000 0x0 0x40000000>;
        };



/* 1GB carved out for my device.*/
        my_device: mydevice@8050000000 {
                compatible = "xxx,xxx-yyy";
                reg = <0x00 0x20810000 0x0 0x010000>,
                      **<0x80 0x50000000 0x0 0x40000000>;**
                interrupts = <GIC_SHARED xx IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
                status = "disabled";
        };
```

Allocation of 1GB was a bit too much and I have modified to it to 256MB but that is not important here.

Then in the driver I retried the memory details as below:

```
struct resource *res;
res = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0); /*this is to get hold of the the registers of my device*/

res = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 1); /* this is the device memory for my device which had been set aside in the dtsi file above.*/

For using the memories retrieve as above use the below:

res->start /* start address of the memory region */
res->end - res->start + 1 /* this is to calculate the size of the memory*/
devm_ioremap_resource(&pdev->dev, res); /* this will give the mapped kernel virtual address for the memory bank*/
```